# Get type of generic at runtime in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, types

How  can I do it properly?

Because this is not working. 
I have a `null` result always `class SomeClass<T>()`

When I try to do `SomeClass<Int>` or something like that I get a null because I dont know how to get type of `Generic` properly.

I already tried to create fields in class, but I want to avoid creating fields in this class

```
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Any> SomeClass<T>.defaultSerializer(): KSerializer<T>? = when (this) {
    String::class -> StringSerializer
    Char::class -> CharSerializer
    Double::class -> DoubleSerializer
    Float::class -> FloatSerializer
    Long::class -> LongSerializer
    Int::class -> IntSerializer
    Short::class -> ShortSerializer
    Byte::class -> ByteSerializer
    Boolean::class -> BooleanSerializer
    Unit::class -> UnitSerializer
    else -> null
} as KSerializer<T>?
```

Comment: Can you add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question? Ideally with an example in [Kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [inline functions with reified types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html). So you're basically on the right track, but your when statement is checking `this` (which in your code is an instance of `SomeClass<T>` against `String::class`, `Char::class`, etc. You instead need to compare the class itself.

What I would recommend is to have an internal method which takes in a `KClass<T>` to switch on, and then a public inline reified function which provides the `KClass` to the internal method. For example:

```
@PublishedApi
internal fun <T : Any> SomeClass<T>.defaultSerializer(
    clazz: KClass<T>
): KSerializer<T>? = when (clazz) {
    String::class -> StringSerializer()
    Char::class -> CharSerializer()
    Double::class -> DoubleSerializer()
    Float::class -> FloatSerializer()
    Long::class -> LongSerializer()
    Int::class -> IntSerializer()
    Short::class -> ShortSerializer()
    Byte::class -> ByteSerializer()
    Boolean::class -> BooleanSerializer()
    Unit::class -> UnitSerializer()
    else -> null
} as KSerializer<T>?

inline fun <reified T: Any> SomeClass<T>.defaultSerializer(): KSerializer<T>? = 
    defaultSerializer(T::class)
```

Then, given an instance of `SomeClass<String>` you can just do:

`someClassString.defaultSerializer()`

The reason for the separate internal and public functions is to avoid inlining the full `when` block everywhere that it's used.